# Checking History From Table And Marking The Record According To That In Mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have a source table with following structure

Table name : Sample

```
    +---+-------+----+--------------------+---------+
    | id|   name| e_id|    date           | a_code |
    +---+-------+----+--------------------+---------+
    |  1|M Malik|A10A|2002-12-03 00:00:00|   018 |
    |  3|M Malik|A10A|1999-02-03 00:00:00|   018 |
    |  4| S Raza|A12A|2006-10-13 00:00:00|   018 |
    |  5| S Raza|A12A|2010-01-23 00:00:00|   018 |
    +---+-------+----+--------------------+---------+
```

Now i have to check every record in the sample that if a_code is apply on same employee two or more year ago if apply than mark this as level 1 else mark this record as level 2
So my result table would look like this

Table name : Result

```
    +---+-------+----+--------------------+---------+
    | id|   name| e_id|    date          |a_code|level
    +---+-------+----+--------------------+---------+
    |  1|M Malik|A10A|2002-12-03 00:00:00|   018 | 1
    |  3|M Malik|A10A|1999-02-03 00:00:00|   018 | 2
    |  4| S Raza|A12A|2006-10-13 00:00:00|   018 | 2
    |  5| S Raza|A12A|2010-01-23 00:00:00|   018 | 1
    +---+-------+----+--------------------+---------+
```

I try to solve it with self joins but i make Cartesian and duplicate the record and give not accurate results.
How can i achieve that...?

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: it tried this query

SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN 
(DATEDIFF(a.`date`,b.`date`)) / 365 >= 2 THEN 1  ELSE 2 END AS level
FROM sample a 
LEFT JOIN sample b ON a.e_id = b.e_id

Comment: After lot of r&d i realize that it is not possible through join. I want to do that with query. How i do that.

Comment: It is possible through cursor but my requirement is through query because i want to use it in code.

Comment: What would be the level number if the date lies in these years (2015 or 2016)? And how many entries are possible to exist in the table for a particular employee?

Comment: Against every record we have to check the history means we have to check previous date against same employee. If same action is performed on same employee 2 or more year ago then we have to marked it as level 1 and in all other cases it will be marked as level 2.
Entries of employee have not limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN y.a_code = x.a_code THEN 1 ELSE 2 END level 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.e_id = x.e_id 
   AND y.a_code = x.a_code 
   AND y.date < x.date - INTERVAL 2 YEAR;
```

`Name` should not be a column in this table.

Comment: thanx @Strawberry you understand it well and and your answer is near to what i am looking for but still it is repeating the record for example if you run the query on the above data sets it is repeating the record with id 1.

Comment: This query returns the desired result for the data set provided above. I was thinking of adding the DISTINCT keyword to the query, but I figured you'd get there yourself. If that doesn't solve it, provide a more throroughly representative dataset, together with the desired result.

Comment: plz add this one more row and observe the ouput
'M Malik', 'A10A', '1994-04-23 00:00:00', '0180'
yes definitely i can use distinct but i am looking for more accurate solution. Your provided solution is working well with distinct. thnx

Comment: That's an accurate solution.

Comment: thanx @ Strawberry