# Scala : Map and Flatmap on RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD with this structure

```
     RDD[((String, String), List[(Int, Timestamp, String)])]
```

and data

```
    ((D2,Saad Arif),List((4,2011-10-05 00:00:00.0,C101), (5,2010-01-27 00:00:00.0,C101)))
    ((D3,Faran Abid),List((7,2016-10-05 00:00:00.0,C101)))
    ((D1,Atif Shahzad),List((1,2012-04-15 00:00:00.0,C101), (2,2011-10-05 00:00:00.0,C101), (3,2006-12-25 00:00:00.0,C101)))
```

consider this as table means

```
   '(D2,Saad Arif)'
```

is like key and

```
    'List((4,2011-10-05 00:00:00.0,C101), (5,2010-01-27 00:00:00.0,C101)'
```

is like rows for this key.
Now i want to check for each row that if there is record(history) with code 'C101' before two or more year then set level to 2 otherwise to 1. So the resulting RDD should look like this

```
((D2,Saad Arif),List((4,2011-10-05 00:00:00.0,C101, 1), (5,2010-01-27 00:00:00.0,C101, 1)))
((D3,Faran Abid),List((7,2016-10-05 00:00:00.0,C101, 1)))
((D1,Atif Shahzad),List((1,2012-04-15 00:00:00.0,C101, 2), (2,2011-10-05 00:00:00.0,C101, 2), (3,2006-12-25 00:00:00.0,C101, 1)))
```

Notice new level after timestamp.How can i do this with map or flatmap?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `map` and `flatMap`? This one is clearly an use-case for `map`.

Comment: Also... Please look at your past questions. And if someone has correctly answered your question, make sure to appreciate that person's effort by marking his answer as accepted.

Comment: @Sarvesh Kumar Singh  yes i have basic idea of map and flat map but i don't know how to use in this scenario.

Comment: @Sarvesh Kumar Singh  I have marked answers accepted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39124475/1151929 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/39013506/1151929

Comment: @@Sarvesh Kumar Singh sorry i did'nt notice these questions. Actually i marked recently posted question so i think i marked all posted question.

Comment: @Sarvesh Kumar Singh please help me on this question

Comment: Atif, if those answers to your previous answers helped you, you should mark them as accepted answers. I'm referring to the links posted above by @SarveshKumarSingh.

Comment: Sarvesh Kumar Singh i marked them accepted

Comment: @AtifShahzad, i don't understand your question quite. Where do we base the additional entry? is it from the `Int` value in each tuple?

Comment: @ John Titus Jungao we have to return List[(Int, Timestamp, String, Int)])] and the last int in tuple4 we have to decide on the basis of history check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.Period    


val df1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")

val futureDate = LocalDate.parse("2100-01-01 00:00:00.0", df1)

val yourRequiredRdd = yourRdd
  .map({
    case (t, list) => {
      val list1 = list.map({
        case (id, dateStr, id2) => (id, LocalDate.parse(dateStr, df1), id2) 
      })

      val oldestDate = list1
        .filter({ case (id, date, id2) => id2.equals("C101") })
        .map(_._2)
        .foldLeft(futureDate)((oldestDate, date) => {
          val period = Period.between(oldestDate, date)
          if (!period.isNegative()) oldestDate else date
        })

      val newList = list1
        .map({
          case (id, date, "C101") => {
            val periodFromOldestDate = Period.between(oldestDate, date)
            val extraNumber = if (periodFromOldestDate.getYears() >= 2) 2 else 1
            (id, date, "C101", extraNumber)
          }
          case (id, date, id2) => {
            (id, date, id2, 1)
          }
        })

      (t, newList)
    }
  })
  .flatMap({
    case ((pid, name), list) => list.map({
      case (id, date, code, level) => (id, name, code, pid, date, level)
    })
  })
```

Comment: thank you very much. Can you  briefly explain the code to find 'oldestDate ' .

Comment: filter out the entries others than `C101` then map to just keep dates. Now you just have a list of dates. Now fold on that list to find the oldest date.

Comment: requiredRDD have this structure 'RDD[((String, String), List[(Int, LocalDate, String, Int)])]' how i map it to 'RDD[(Int, String, String, String, LocalDate, Int)]' by something using map { case ((pid, name), (id, date, code, level)) => (id, name, code, pid, date, level) }

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: thanx i needed that